# Reindexing in Elasticsearch 1.7

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

There is a problem with our mappings for elasticsearch 1.7. I am fixing the problem by creating a new index with the correct mappings. I understand that since I am creating a new index I will have to reindex from old index with existing data to the new index I have just created. Problem is I have googled around and can't find a way to reindex from old to new. Seems like the reindex API was introduced in ES 2.3 and not supported for 1.7.

My question is how do I reindex my data from old to new after fixing my mappings. Alternatively, what is the best practice for making mapping changes in ES 1.7?

1. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html will not work for me because we're on an old version of ES (1.7)
2. https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime
   Initially went down that path but got stuck, need a way to reindex the old to the new

Comment: It would probably be a good investment to upgrade Elasticsearch. 5.x supports remote reindex, so you can pull your data from 1.7. Otherwise you're flogging a dead horse and any investment here (like a custom reindex strategy) is pretty much wasted.

Comment: Not always possible. We use something on top of Elastic which locks us to v1 of Elastic, so answers to this question are legitimately useful.

Answer (score 1):

Late for your use case, but wanted to put it out there for others. This is an excellent step-by-step guide on how to reindex an Elasticsearch index using Logstash version 1.5 while maintaining the integrity of the original data: http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2015/05/20/reindex-elasticsearch-with-logstash/

This is the `logstash-simple.conf` the author creates:

```
Input {
  # We read from the "old" cluster
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost" ]
    port => "9200"
    index => "index"
    size => 500
    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "@timestamp", "@version" ]
  }
}

output {
  # We write to the "new" cluster
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
    port => "9200"
    protocol => "http"
    index => "new_index"
    index_type => "%{[@metadata][_type]}"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
  # We print dots to see it in action
  stdout {
    codec => "dots"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options for you:

use logstash - it's very easy to create a reindex config in logstash and use that to reindex your documents. for example:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost" ]
    port => "9200"
    index => "index1"
    size => 1000
    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
  }
}


output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
    port => "9200"
    protocol => "http"
    index => "index2"
    index_type => "%{[@metadata][_type]}"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
}
```

The problem with this approach that it'll be relatively slow since you'll have only a single machine that peforms the reindexing process.

another option, use this [tool](https://github.com/allegro/elasticsearch-reindex-tool). It'll be faster than logstash but you'll have to provide a segmentation logic for all your documents to speed up the processing. For example, if you have a numeric fields whose values range from 1 - 100, then you could segment the queries in the tool for, maybe, 10 intervals (1 - 10, 11 - 20, ... 91 - 100), so the tool will spawn up 10 indexers that will work in parallel reindexing your old index.